# Receiving An Intermittent EXC_BAD_ACCESS When Updating an EKEvent

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access

I have a Cordova app with a custom plugin that is creating and updating EKEvents in the user's iCloud calendar.

I am using the following function to find a specific EKEvent based on its URL:

```
- (EKEvent*) getEventWithURL:(NSString *)pstrURL store:(EKEventStore *)pStore
{


    EKCalendar* calendar = [self getCalendarByName:mstrCalendarName store:pStore createIfDoesNotExist:false];

    NSArray* calendars = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: calendar, nil];

    NSDateFormatter *sDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [sDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    NSDate *myStartDate = [sDate dateFromString:@"2013-11-01 00:00"];


    NSDateFormatter *eDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [eDate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"];
    NSDate *myEndDate = [eDate dateFromString:@"2014-12-31 23:59"];

    NSPredicate *predicate = [pStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:myStartDate endDate:myEndDate calendars: calendars];

    // Fetch all events that match the predicate.
    NSArray *events = [pStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

    EKEvent *foundEvent = nil;
    EKEvent *event;

    for (id oEvent in events)
    {
        event = (EKEvent *)oEvent;

        if ([event.URL isEqual:[NSURL URLWithString:pstrURL]])
        {
            foundEvent = event;
            break;
        }
    }

    return foundEvent;
}
```

It is then modified (start and end dates are changed) and saved in another method with the following code:

```
EKEvent *myEvent = nil;

BOOL saved = false;


EKCalendar* calendar = nil;

if(pstrCalendarTitle == nil)
{
    calendar = pStore.defaultCalendarForNewEvents;
}
else
{
    calendar = [self getCalendarByName: pstrCalendarTitle store: pStore createIfDoesNotExist:true];
}


// find event if it exists
myEvent = [self getEventWithURL:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"custom://%@", pstrTSDID ] store:pStore];


// if an event wasn't found, create a new one
if (myEvent == nil)
{
    myEvent = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore: pStore];
}

// set all the fields to new values
myEvent.title = pstrTitle;
myEvent.location = pstrLocation;
myEvent.notes = pstrMessage;
myEvent.startDate = pdtStartDate;
myEvent.endDate = pdtEndDate;
myEvent.calendar = calendar;
myEvent.URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"custom://%@", pstrTSDID ]];

// only add an alarm if one hasn't been created already
if ([[myEvent alarms] count] == 0)
{
    EKAlarm *reminder = [EKAlarm alarmWithRelativeOffset:-2*60*60];
    [myEvent addAlarm:reminder];
}
```

When creating a whole bunch of EKEvents (about 30 in a row) I don't get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error, however when updating events I get the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error intermittently. Sometimes it is on the first update, and sometimes I am able to update 10 before seeing the error, which then crashes my app.

I suspect it may have something to do with the foundEvent variable not being retained, however my project is using ARC so it is my understanding that I don't need to do any memory management tasks. Unless ARC is getting confused with the way the event variable is being cast and then passed around in the loop in `getEventWithURL`?

For full disclosure, I do have `Enable Zombie Objects` enabled and the stack trace that I see doesn't reference any of my methods specifically, it starts at start_wqthread and then references some `EKEventStore _databasechangedexternally` internal methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth I wasn't able to figure out what the issue was with modifying the events so I am instead deleting the event (if it exists) and creating a new one. My `getEventWithURL` method is now called `deleteEventWithURL` which does the removal of the event from the store. The app is no longer crashing after making this change.